# What Automations, processes etc, can manipulate a field's value?

Tags: automated-process

df-- This post started as a local issue I had, however, it got me thinking, to try and collect all the different scenarios, options, flows, automations etc, that can manipulate data, for others to have some kind of a guide.

I have an issue, where I try to change an opportunity currency, it automatically changes to EUR:
[image]

- in this example, I changed from USD to ILS, and it changed to EUR

I looked in the following :

- Workflow rules/Field updates - none are changing the CurrencyIsoCode field
- Flows - couldn't see a flow that changes the value [[Update - this was the culprit]]
- Process builder - same
- I look for the CurrencyIsoCode field in APEX - nothing was effecting it's value.
- Look for installed packages that manipulate the field

What other features/automations exist, where I should look for ?

I mean, what other Salesforce features can make this change?

I tried to add a debug log for Automation Process - didn't see anything.

Adding a small piece of information:

```
My user default currency is: USD
My Corporate default currency is: USD
```

Comment: Do you have any installed packages that manipulate the currency field?

Comment: If you have a license for [event monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring), you should be able to find this in EventLogFile